# Looking for a proper name for this vector subspaces

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, terminology, stirling-numbers, q-analogs

Let $K^n$ be the vector space of rows of length $n$ over $K$. A subspace $S$ is called *coordinately complete* if for every $i\ (1 \leq i \leq n)$ there is an element in $S$ with a nonzero $i$th coordinate.

The number $V_q(n,t)$ of all coordinately complete $t$-dimensional subspaces of $K^n$ with $K=GF(q)$ is
$$V_q(n,t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-t}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}{n-k \brack t}_q.$$
(Here ${n \brack k}_q$ is well-known $q$-binomial coefficient.)

Let $\text{S}_q[n,t]$ be the $q$-Stirling number of the second kind. Today I've found that
$$V_q(n,t) = \frac{(q-1)^{n-t}}{q^{t(t-1)/2}}\text{S}_q[n,t].$$

The name of *coordinately complete subspaces* was invented by the authors (including me) of the recent paper [1]. After finding connection with $q$-Stirling numbers I suspect this subspaces might have a proper name in existing literature. I will appreciate any reference.

1. Enveloping algebras and ideals of the niltriangular subalgebra of the Chevalley algebra. G. Egorychev et al. Siberian Mathematical Journal, 2023, Vol. 64, No. 2, pp. 300–317.